# Adding an executable binary to kernel image

Tags: linux-kernel, binary, linux-device-driver, clock

I have a driver (not dealing with any file operations but just a .c file) which reads all clock configuration registers and calculates the clocks present on the board and it will print them on the console.

My question is can we add this .c file and build some .bin binary so that if we execute it from the console it should print the clocks.

Comment: what do you mean by driver ? do you mean kernel device driver ? If so if you are root then of course you can insmod that driver or even add it to your config during building of the kernel.

Comment: Sorry, Its just a C file which reads some hardware registers and calculate clock based on the register's value.  

I want it to build like an executable named lets say "clock_info" so that whenever I type clock_info on the console the one function in that C file should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and explanation are contradictory. If you want driver to be in-built to kernel image then you won't get .ko(.bin) file to execute it later.

For your requirement I would suggest you to write a userspace application which reads registry values (may be using mmap) and print the output on console. You may place this binary in `/usr/bin` directory, so that the binary is accessible in console directly.

Comment: Sorry for that contradiction.

Comment: Looks like a good idea Vikram. Will give it a try and get back to you. Thank you